# How Poco::SharedLibrary loading and instantiating classes?

Tags: poco-libraries

I know that dynamic libraries can be loaded by Poco::SharedLibrary as below:

```
using PocoLibraryPtr = std::shared_ptr<Poco::SharedLibrary>;
poco_library = PocoLibraryPtr(new Poco::SharedLibrary(library_path));
```

I see in the code that the class is instantiated directly after loading. Is this feasible? Currently this code works fine.

```
template <typename ClassObject, typename Base>
class ClassFactory : public AbstractClassFactory<Base> {
 public:
  ClassFactory(const std::string& class_name,
               const std::string& base_class_name)
      : AbstractClassFactory<Base>(class_name, base_class_name) {}

  Base* CreateObj() const { return new ClassObject; }
};
```

When the class is loaded, then the code use

```
classobj = factory->CreateObj();
```

to create the class. I did not find similar usage online. Is there any code I didn't notice?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a shared library to create an object using a templatized factory class.

Template instantiations are static polymorphic so the factory object needs to be determined at compile time.

In other words, no, that won't work.

If you specifically want **Poco** **SharedLibrary** help, take a look at the **Poco** documentation for more help: https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.SharedLibrary.html.

Or look at the slides here: https://pocoproject.org/slides/120-SharedLibraries.pdf